# Send data to apple watch

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, watchos

I have apple watch series 4 and an iPhone. I want to send data like links,images,text to my watch. Usually I emailed these data to myself and open it on my watch .

> Is there any efficient way to do it ? 
>   Any app or something ?

My watch is constantly connected with iPhone via Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler method would be to use Messages to send a message to yourself with the text, links, and images. They would show up as notifications on the watch making it easy to tap into them - instead of having to open up Mail, find the right mail, open attachment, etc.